# Mongoengine ORM filtering on referenced items in ListField

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Consider the following using MongoEngine:

```
class Files(Document):
    name = StringField()
    access_time = DateTimeField()
    size = IntField()

class Folders(Document):
    name = StringField()
    files = ListField(field=ReferenceField('Files'))
```

If I wish to get files in a folder filtered by some attribute (name/access_time/size), what is a good way?

I can iterate over the list (maybe by using no_cache()), but that would take a lot of time if objects are more.

How to elegantly filter ListField having references in MongoEngine?

Comment: what version of mongodb are you connecting to?

Answer (score 1):

The document references are only stored as a list of ObjectID's in mongodb so you will need mongoengine to dereference them to do any kind of filtering.

You have three options to get around this:

Store the reference on Files objects:

```
class Files(Document):
    name = StringField()
    access_time = DateTimeField()
    size = IntField()
    folder = ReferenceField(Folders)

folder = Folders.objects.first()
big_files = Files.objects(size__gt=500,folder=folder).all()
```

Store the files as Embedded Documents:

```
class Files(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField()
    access_time = DateTimeField()
    size = IntField()

class Folders(Document):
    name = StringField()
    files = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Files)
```

Use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/):

```
pipeline = [
    {"$unwind": "$files"},
    {"$lookup":
        {
            "from": "files",
            "localField": "files",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "files"
        }},
    {"$unwind": "$files"},
    {"$match": {"files.size": {"$gt": 500}}},
    {"$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": {"$first": "$name"},
        "files": {"$push": "$files"}
    }},

]

folders = Folders.objects.aggregate(*pipeline)
```

Which you use will be based on your real application but not that the `$lookup` on the aggregation pipeline is only available from mongodb version 3.2 an does not work on sharded collections.

Comment: First option works for me. Thanks.